# HTML 5 video CSS: Force responsive ratio 16:9 on video poster image (for preload="none" videos)

Tags: html, css, video, html5-video, aspect-ratio

Assuming that the poster size of an HTML 5 video should always be 16:9 but the height of the actual video is still auto. How can I make the poster image stick to those dimensions (it shall be cutted to fit the dimensions e.g. with object-fit)?

```css
video {
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}

video[poster] {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<video poster="https://i.imgur.com/LFgR8jD.png" controls="controls" class="pimcore_video" preload="none">
<source type="video/mp4" src="https://storage.coverr.co/videos/sksZ7cBoTBAJkB4Bul46QAI1c01x7lx18?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHBJZCI6IjExNDMyN0NEOTRCMUFCMTFERTE3IiwiaWF0IjoxNTg3MDMwNzIwfQ.moAIavql_5_ggd9hrKExX6iPeo2UM_CMya6Mozg4hyY">
</video>
```

As you can see in the snippet above the size of the poster image is different to the video itself.

Comment: you are missing a `;` in your code

Comment: @TemaniAfif True, edited.